# cast a jsonb value to varchar in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

I have a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT (value->'Tag') AS tagname 
FROM documents, 
     jsonb_array_elements(documents.Tags)
```

so the tagname is a jsonb value. I need to cast that tagname to varchar. How do I do that cast?

sample data in Tags column in documents table is

```
'[{"Tag":"Web 2.0"},{"Tag":"Adobe Creative"},{"Tag":"Suite"}]'
```

I am working on java jpa. I tried the native query as

```
Query query = this.em.createNativeQuery(
            "select distinct (value->'Tag')::varchar as tags from documents, jsonb_array_elements(documents.Tags)");
```

but its showing

```
Not all named parameters have been set:
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need for a cast, simply use the [`->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) which returns the value as `text`

```
SELECT DISTINCT value ->> 'Tag' AS tagname 
FROM documents, 
     jsonb_array_elements(documents.tags);
```

---

As you might need a cast for something different someday:

`::` isn't the only way to cast a value (and which is what JPA chokes on). You can also use the standard `cast()` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cast(value -> 'Tag' as varchar) AS tagname
```

But the `->>` operator is the better choice here.